# При клике по метке делать полупрозрачными другие объекты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Возник еще один вопрос по Яндекс картам.

На карте есть различные объекты: метки, полигоны, линии. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при клике по объекту на карте все объекты кроме того, по которому кликнули, стали полупрозрачными.

А при клике по кноке "reset" объекты должны вернуться к изначальному состоянию.

Наиболее очевидное решение -- создать отдельную коллекцию геообъектов, задать ей options и помещать при клике помещать внутри нее все объекты, кроме активного.

Так удается решить проблему запоминания исходного состояния объектов: свойства коллекции автоматически отменяются при переносе объекта из одной коллекции в другую.

Однако сложность заключается в том, что показатели прозрачности у разных объектов тоже различаются: у линий -- один тип прозрачности, у полигонов другой. Кроме того есть вероятность что к показателям прозрачности неактивных элементов в дальнейшем добавятся свойства обводки, прозрачности линий, цвета и т.п.

Я накидал пример задачи в песочнице, чтобы было нагляднее

http://output.jsbin.com/biqihiq/24/

Здесь уже реализовано желаемое поведение, однако здесь нельзя задавать отдельные параметры options для каждого типа геометрии.

Как можно этого добиться?

Спасибо.

UPD: добавил решение предложенное se0ga. Из недостатков:

1) слишком много кода -- 3 дополнительных коллекции, усложненные функции выделения активного элемента

2) не получилось задать параметры strokeOpacity, strokeWidth для коллекции неактивных линий (unactiveLineCollection). А вот strokeColor прекрасно сработал, почему-то. Есть идеи, почему так происходит? Аналогичные опции с полигоном работают прекрасно: установленные опции перезаписываются теми, что прописаны в коллекции, а с линией не работает...

Пример с этим решением есть тут:

http://jsbin.com/jiletut/2

Comment: Ваш пример не работает.

Comment: Поправил ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете создать свои коллекции для каждого типа геообъектов и настроить их. Подписаться на клик по каждой коллекции и изменять опции объектов внутри них.

```
var target;  
myGeoObjects.events.add('click', function(e){
    if(target) {
        target.options.unset('iconOpacity');
        target.options.unset('opacity');
    }

    target = e.get('target');
    target.options.set('iconOpacity', 1);
});    
myGeoObjects2.events.add('click', function(e){
    if(target) {
        target.options.unset('iconOpacity');
        target.options.unset('opacity');
    }

    target = e.get('target');
    target.options.set('opacity', 1);
})
```

Накидал пример: http://jsfiddle.net/ekdyLhg5/

Comment: Спасибо за пример! Технически можно конечно создать отдельные коллекции для каждого типа геометрии (для активного и неактивного состояния, всего 6 коллекций), и перемещать объекты из одной коллекции в другую, но хотелось бы найти более лаконичное решение.

Comment: Зачем перемещать объекты из коллекции в коллекцию? Я показываю подход при котором этого делать не надо. Если вам нужно настроить, чтобы отличалась прозрачность у полигонов и линий, то технически это разные коллекции. Коллекция с прозрачностью n и коллекция с прозрачностью m.

Comment: В примере геообъекты создаются без свойств. Свойства присваиваются им тогда, когда они перемещаются в коллекцию. При клике по геообъекту свойство перезаписывается, а у прошлого активного геообъекта оно обнуляется.
Мне нужно чтобы свойства были указаны уже при создании (они высчитываются на основании данных из бд), при клике по объекту его прозрачность, например, не устанавливалась вручную = 1, а становилась такой же, как и была до установления прозрачности. Как добиться такого поведения без перемещения объекта из коллекции в коллекцию?

Comment: "Мне нужно чтобы свойства были указаны уже при создании (они высчитываются на основании данных из бд)" - это начальная геоколлекция.  "При клике по объекту его прозрачность, например, не устанавливалась вручную = 1, а становилась такой же, как и была до установления прозрачности." - Вот тут не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать, вы рассматриваете первый клик при котором вы хотите видоизменить внешний вид чего-то, например метки? Тогда откуда до первого клика появляется состояние которое было до установления прозрачности?

Comment: Наверно я не очень понятно объяснил, посмотрите на первый пример в сообщении:
1) изначально все объекты отрисовываются с определенными параметрами (из бд).
2) когда мы кликаем по объекту, параметры всех объектов, кроме тех, по которому кликнули, меняются в зависимости от типа геометрии: например, у полигонов показатель прозрачности ниже, чем у линий (это у меня не получилось)
3) когда мы еще раз кликаем по другому объекту, происходит то же самое, что и в п.2, а у прошлого объекта, по которому мы кликнули в п.2, восстанавливаются те свойства, которые были заданы в п.1.

Comment: Ну тогда несколько коллекций видимо ваш вариант.